# DataStax Cassandra community edition integration with Hive 0.96.0

Tags: cassandra, integration, hive

I have been looking to find a solution to integrate DataStax community edition Cassandra 1.1 with Hive 0.96 and i am not able to find a solution yet. There are pointers to use the storage handler to integrate much older version of Cassandra and Hive.

Is DataStax Cassandra Enterprise edition, the only solution?